# store refreshing or not saving state vue.js 3

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I have a vue 3 app in which saves whether the user is Authenticated and Active in the store after they log-in. With my current implementation, it works as expected when I first login. However, when I click on another tab and come back, I am redirected to the login page. Which means the store is not saving the state.

Why is my store not saving state?

```
const showDetails = () => {
    if (props.course.subscription && store.authenticated && store.activated) {
        console.log("Course selected: here")
        store.updatePreviousCourseSelected(props.course)
        router.push({name: 'courseDetails'})
    } else if (props.course.subscription && store.authenticated == false) {
        console.log("props.course.subscription " + props.course.subscription)
        console.log("store.activated " + store.activated) <--- false
        console.log("store.authenticated " + store.authenticated) <--- false
        router.push({name: 'login'})
    } else {
        store.updatePreviousCourseSelected(props.course)
        router.push({name: 'courseDetails'})
    }
}
```

login.vue

```
const store = useStore();

const login = () => {
    api.login(email.value, password.value).then((res) => {
        if (res.success) {
            store.activated = res.activated
            store.authenticated = true
            console.log("I am active : " + store.activated) 
            console.log("I am authenticated : " + store.authenticated)
            localStorage.setItem("token", res.token)
            router.push({name: "courses"})
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        //TODO: add a metric here...
        alert("Invalid credentials")
    })
}
```

Comment: @Phil I am using pinia

Comment: You'd better provide a minimal runnable demo, such as on codesandbox. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example